# merge multiple JSON or output single JSON file in python

Tags: python, json, merge

In this python script i am making a REST call to a server and pulling information out in JSON files. With the following code, I am outputting 4 JSON files into a folder. I would like to output only 1 json file with all the information I need, how would I do this?
 If that's not possible then I would think merging the 4 JSON files would be my only option? Any help would be appreciated.

```
from subprocess import call
import os
import json
from glob import glob

fileName = "IP.txt"
file = open(fileName, "r")
for str in file:
login_info = str.split(':')
ip = login_info[0] 
username = login_info[1]
password = login_info[2]
os.mkdir(ip)

  call(["ilorest", "login", ip, '-u', 
  username, '-p', password])

  call(["ilorest", "save", '-- 
  selector=ComputerSystem', '--json', '-f', 
  ip+"\\"+ip+".json"])

  call(["ilorest", "save", '-- 
  selector=Memory', '--json', '-f', 
  ip+"\\"+ip+"_memory"+".json"])

  call(["ilorest", "save", '-- 
  selector=Processor', '--json', '-f', 
  ip+"\\"+ip+"_processor"+".json"])

  call(["ilorest", "save", '-- 
  selector=HPESmartStorageDiskDrive', '-- 
  json', '-f', 
  ip+"\\"+ip+"_drives"+".json"])

  call(["ilorest", "logout"])


paths = glob('*/')
for d in paths:
print(os.dir(d))
```

Comment: You can add all four elements to a list and just save the list as JSON. Look at `subprocess.check_output`

Comment: If merge were the solution, how would you do that? How shall the result look like? What do you want to have inside of it?

Comment: All the files have the exact same format, in fact, the first section of them are identical. The only reason i want them as a single file is because it will be easier for me to parse them and load them onto my sql table. I rather have 1 very long file for each IP than 4 files for each IP.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a dict with all json objects, and dump it:

```
types = ['', '_memory', '_processor', '_drives']

result = {}
for suffix in types:
    with open(os.path.join(ip, ip + suffix + '.json')) as f:
        result[suffix.strip('_')] = json.load(f)
with open(os.path.join(ip, ip+ '_all.json'), 'w') as fw:
    json.dump(result, fw)
```

Comment: Do i simply add that to the end of my file or should i edit my code somwhere?

Comment: @JohnMonte just add that. It will read all 4 files and generate a single file with the contents. That said, you might want to check the library from the other answer, because doing everything inside your python process seems more efficient than calling a subprocess 4 times. And then you could generate a single file in first place thus avoiding the merge.

Comment: Thats where I started to try to figure out if i can do a single process for all the information i needed. I will look at it again but i believe  the calls have to be made separate, ill look again however because i agree its terrible inefficient. Thank you for your help!